# matlab: how to combine two TIFF file into a multipage TIFF

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, save, tiff

i have many tiff files which they should be combined, so that each two file should be combine into one.
I wrote a java program using JAI library to do that. But its slow and creates multipage files almost 4 in a second, But i need to reach 20 in a second. So i decide to search about matlab. I shall be thankful if you could let me know following questions:

1. Is it possible to reach this speed by matlab?
2. How can i do that by matlab?

I haven't experience in matlab programming. So it is better to give me the code. :)

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'append' writemode of the [imwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html?refresh=true) function to create a multi-page Tiff.

eg.

```
for k = 1:NumImages

  imwrite(YourMovie{k},SomeName,'tif','WriteMode','append');

end
```

in which YourMovie is a cell array containing your frames and SomeName is the name of your tiff file.

Note that you can replace YourMovie by anything that actually contains your image... like YourMovieArray(:,:,:,k) if they are stored in a 4D array for example.